# Actions on Google - Unable to use "quick account linking"

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I set up my Actions on Google project with account linking enabled and the Implicit flow, it's working fine. However, when I try to select "Add quick account linking", after I save and click "Test Draft", it goes to the simulator page with an error message "Failed to enable simulator".

The error happens whether I select "Account creation", "Auto Google Sign-in" or both. I've filled the fields "GSI Client ID", "Token URL" and "Learn More URL" with proper values.

I can see under the hood that a POST query is made to https://console.actions.google.com/u/0/m/actions/agents/draft/createlocalizeduserpreview and returns a 500 error with "status":13. When I unselect "Add quick account linking", the same query succeeds and no error is displayed.

Did anyone get this to work?

Comment: Hi I made a question about implicit account linking some days ago, cause for me its not working at all. How did you managed to get it working? are you doing it with dialogflow / api.ai or directly with action sdk?

Comment: I’m using the action sdk with my own server behind. Try using the phone app to test the signin (it opens the /auto endpoint in a browser, which the simulator doesn’t seem able to do).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will try later at home

Answer (score 0):

Did you [follow the steps to extend the Implicit flow](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-assertion-flow#overview) and add a new endpoint that would handle the assertion request based on a JWT? This needs to be a new endpoint, and is similar to what you needed to do if you were implementing the Auth Code flow.

If so, verify that this endpoint is being called, that you're parsing the JWT correctly, and that you're returning either an auth code or a valid redirect to have the user sign-in.

Comment: Yes I did, but it’s never being called. Because of the error when I do “Test Draft”, it looks like the quick account linking settings are not applied.